# Find all $ p \ge 1 $ for which the Hölder norm $\|\cdot\|_p $ is generated by a scalar product.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Find all $ p \ge 1 $for which the Hölder norm $$ \|x\|_p := \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1} |x_i|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} $$ is generated by a scalar product.

We know that norm is generated by a scalar product iff it satisfies the identity of the parallelogram $ \|x+y\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2 = 2(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2) $

Using it I can for example prove that if $ p = 1 $ norm is not generated by any scalar product, but if $ p = 2 $ it is generated.

But how does it generalize and find all $ p $ for which the norm is generated by the scalar product?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just compute with $x=(1,0,0,\ldots)$ and $y=(0,1,0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: But it's not a proof...

Comment: They don't satisfy the equality for $p=1$ (the LHS is then $8$  and the RHS is $4$). The equality is not satisfied for these vectors for any  $p\ne2$; this shows the norm is not induced from an inner product for $p\ne2$.

Comment: O, yes, great thanks!